# For any action map, why is there always a G-set X such that the action map is injective?

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G,*,id_G)$ be a group.
We say that $G$ *acts* on $X$, or that $X$ is a *$G$-set*, if we have a map $\cdot: G \times X \to X$ such that the following hold:

(i) Associativity:  $(g_1*g_2)\cdot x = g_1 \cdot (g_2 \cdot x)$ for all $g_1,g_2\in G$ and $x\in X$.

(ii) Identity: $id_g \cdot x = x$ for all $x\in X$.

Such a mapping, $\cdot$, is called an *action map*.

I showed that $X$ is a $G$-set is equivalent to existence of a map, $\alpha:G\to \text{Aut}(X)$, the set of bijections on $X$, such that $\alpha(g *g')=\alpha(g)\circ \alpha(g')$ for every $g,g'\in G$.

Then I am asked to show that there is a $G$-set $X$ such that the natural map, $\alpha$, that I defined is an injection.

Maybe I am missing something, but I don't think that this is always possible. For example, if $g\cdot x=x$ for all $g\in G$ and $x\in X$, then $\cdot$ is an action map. Then, the natural choice of $\alpha$ sends $g$ to $id_X$ for all $g\in G$. If $G$ is not the trivial group, then this mapping will never be injective.

Comment: You are right that not all actions $G$ satisfy this property. But that's not what you were asked to show. You were asked to show the *existence* of some action of $G$ that satisfies this property.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the map $\cdot:G\times G\to G$ given by $g\cdot h=g*h$.  Show that this is an action, and that the induced map $\alpha$ is injective.